# how to add a date column to a flatfile

Tags: linux, shell

I'm accessing a public data set around wiki page views that comes in the following format:

```
projectcode, pagename, pageviews, bytes
```

and the file name looks like this:

```
pagecounts-20090430-230000.gz
```

I want to process this file so that the date info from the file name is in the data file...so I would look for something like this:

```
date, projectcode, pagename, pageviews, bytes
```

I'm guess I have to use SED function? I've used it to process strings but not a data file itself...how would one do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the date - the first cut returns the part before the first ".", the second one returns the parts following the first "-":

```
DATEPART=$(echo $FILENAME| cut -d"." -f1| cut -d"-" -f2-)
```

Using sed you can then replace all starts of lines:

```
sed -i 's/^/'$DATEPART' /g' $FILENAME
```

Comment: what is this part doing?? 's/^/'

Comment: The regex ^ means "start of line"
See http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: What do you want as delimiter: ",": then s/^/'$DATEPART',/g'. You don't need "&". Or did you want "&" as delimiter?

Comment: no, not the &, just ","...I thought you need the & to concatenate....so its just sed -i 's/^/'$DATEPART' ,/g' $FILENAME?

Comment: yes, we are replacing "start of line", which does not contain anything really, so there is no need backreferencing it.